# How with COUNT() and/or AVG() in my Select

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, count, average

I have a table that I want to run for a months worth of data based on my mopactivity.calldate field.  I want to be able to get the average of the daily calls as daily count for each day of the month.  Can I get a monthly average of calls too?  How would you do this with the COUNT() and/or AVERAGE() commands?  Is there a way to do the average for just weekdays and not the weekend dates? My SELECT statement looks the one below.

```
SELECT mopactivity.mopid,
mopactivity.mopstatus,
mopactivity.calldate
FROM mopactivity
where mopactivity.calldate between to_date('01-JAN-13') 
and to_date('31-JAN-13 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Counts by Day**

To get the daily count (Oracle syntax):

```
-- Oracle
SELECT
  TRUNC(CallDate) AS Dt,
  COUNT(*) AS DailyCount
FROM MOPActivity
WHERE CallDate > DATE '2013-01-01' AND CallDate < '2013-02-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(CallDate)
```

If you're using MySQL, replace both instances of `TRUNC(CallDate)` above with `DATE(CallDate)`:

```
-- MySQL
SELECT
  DATE(CallDate) AS Dt,
  COUNT(*) AS DailyCount
FROM MOPActivity
WHERE CallDate > DATE '2013-01-01' AND CallDate < '2013-02-01'
GROUP BY DATE(CallDate)
```

The query above will report only the days that have call activity, so if, for example, there aren't any calls on Sunday 1/6/2013, there won't be a row for that date.

**Monthly Average**

Oracle will allow you to nest the aggregate functions up to two levels, and this can be used to get a monthly average by doing an `AVG` of the `COUNT`:

```
-- Oracle
SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) AS MonthlyAverage,
FROM MOPActivity
WHERE CallDate > DATE '2013-01-01' AND CallDate < '2013-02-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(CallDate)
```

MySQL doesn't support this, so if you're using MySQL you can just push the daily count query into a subquery and have an outer query calculate the average:

```
-- MySQL
SELECT AVG(DailyCount) AS MonthlyAverage
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE(CallDate) AS Dt,
    COUNT(*) AS DailyCount
  FROM MOPActivity
  WHERE CallDate > DATE '2013-01-01' AND CallDate < '2013-02-01'
  GROUP BY DATE(CallDate)
) DayCounts
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a GROUP BY clause, Group functions like COUNT, SUM and AVG will operate on each group.  So you want to create queries with various groupings using your call date as a basis.  Im assuming calldate is a datetime column, so you can utilize a variety of techniques to isolate these groupings, along with the DATE_FORMAT command to get daily, weekly and monthly groupings.  Use these variations for your GROUP BY and your AVG and COUNTs will work as you expect.

There are also a lot of tricks you can do with the ternary IF() function to isolate your groups in special ways (isolate weeks from weekends).